# VSCode - Reference a type of a module from JS

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image: VisualStudioCode]

Using Visual Studio Code for **JS** programming I can access some features from typescript; since the editor will parse all `.d.ts` files around, it'll help me with variable types. For example it does recognize the following:

*any.js*

```
/** 
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {Promise<Person>}
 */
function foo(s){ ... }

foo('Jhon').then((p) => p.name )
```

*index.d.ts*

```
interface Person { 
  name: string 
  surname: string
}
```

Now, I want to access types (interfaces, classes... whatever) declared in **`node.d.ts`** declaration file; for example it declares the module `stream` which declares the `Readable` interface.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
const stream = require('stream')

/**
 * @param {stream.Readable} stream
 */
function goo(stream) { ... }
```

But that does not work.I've tried with:

- {internal.Readable}
- {stream.Readable}
- {Node.stream.Readable}
- {Node.Readable}
- {Node.internal.Readable}

Answer (score 2):

As of VS Code 1.18, this is a limitation when using `require` with JSDoc types. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19476) to track this specifically

Some possible workarounds:

Use `import`:

```
import * as stream from 'stream'

/**
 * @param {stream.Readable} stream
 */
function goo(stream) { ... }
```

or import `Readable` explicitly:

```
const stream = require('stream')
const {Readable} = require('stream')

/**
 * @param {Readable} stream
 */
function goo(stream) { ... }
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377 also tracks allowing you to specify module imports in jsdocs directly.